# Java Data-Entity model: Constructing general types

Tags: java, refactoring

I have had some trouble with using a general type in a static method.

All comments on the source code are welcome, especially ones that significantly improve the code. I am also currently not planning on using any external framework, apart from JDBC, to keep it still simple, please do not put too much emphasis on that.

My view on not using external frameworks is also supported by the fact that the operations I will be using on the database are very minimal:

- Inserting data
- Updating data
- Retrieving **all** fields. (And simply by putting in a different SQL Query you could already select what fields to retrieve

I do not plan on making a full framework, so I know that it will not be supporting everything. The speed of retrieving all fields is neither a real issue, as this will be pretty much only done on server bootup, and if used at any other time it will be done in a background task for which I do not really care when it is finished.

Entity.java:

```
abstract public class Entity<KeyType, DataType> {
    protected KeyType key;
    protected List<Object> data;

    public Entity() {
        data = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //abstract public static Map<KeyType, DataType> getAll();

    protected List<Object> createData(final DataAction dataAction) {
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (dataAction == DataAction.INSERT) {
            list.add(key);
        }

        list.addAll(data);

        if (dataAction == DataAction.UPDATE) {
            list.add(key);
        }
        return list;
    }

    abstract public void insert();

    abstract public void update();

    protected static <KeyType, DataType> Map<KeyType, DataType> getData(final Class<DataType> dataTypeClass, final String query) {
        Map<KeyType, DataType> map = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = DatabaseConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                KeyType key = (KeyType)resultSet.getObject(1);
                int index = 2;
                List<Object> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
                while (resultSet.getObject(index) != null) {
                    dataList.add(resultSet.getObject(index));
                    index++;
                }
                DataType dataObject = null;
                try {
                    dataObject = dataTypeClass.getConstructor(List.class).newInstance(dataList);
                } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Entity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                map.put(key, dataObject);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Entity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }        
        return map;
    }

    protected void executeQuery(final String query, final List<Object> data) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = DatabaseConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
            int dataIndex = 0;
            for (Object dataObject : data) {
                preparedStatement.setObject(dataIndex, dataObject);
                dataIndex++;
            }
            preparedStatement.execute();
            preparedStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Entity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

A concrete implementation, Account.java:

```
public class Account extends Entity<String, Account> {
    private final static String SELECT_ALL_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM accounts";
    private final static String INSERT_QUERY = "INSERT INTO accounts (username, password) VALUES(?, ?)";
    private final static String UPDATE_QUERY = "UPDATE accounts SET password=? WHERE username=?";

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public Account(final String username, final String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;

        key = username;
        data.add(password);
    }

    public Account(final List<Object> data) {
        this((String)data.get(0), (String)data.get(1));
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(final String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(final String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public static Map<String, Account> selectAll() {
        return getData(Account.class, SELECT_ALL_QUERY);
    }

    @Override
    public void insert() {
        executeQuery(INSERT_QUERY, createData(DataAction.INSERT));
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        executeQuery(UPDATE_QUERY, createData(DataAction.UPDATE));
    }
}
```

I am generally happy about the concrete implementation, it seems like I have managed to bring it down to a bare minimum, except `public Account(final List<Object> data)` does not seem that nice, but I can live with it.

However, as guessed, the `getData()` from `Entity` is definately not nice, and I would like to improve it if possible.

What I would like to use is something like `DataType dataObject = new DataType(dataList)`, but it seems like Generic Type Arguments cannot be instantiated.

So are there any ways of optimizing my current code in my current view? And is it possible to decouple the concrete classes and abstract classes even more?

EDIT:

Added a relevant question (I don't think I should make a fully new question for this thing, right?):

Is there a way to move the static Strings (SQL Queries) and the `insert()` and `update()` out of the Account class, into the Entity class?

Comment: For making CRUD operations I'd recommend using `JPA`. I know that's not what you wanted to hear, but really, why reinvent the wheel, when it's already invented for you? If you're using an IDE like Netbeans, it can autocreate the classes for you. Also you're not taking care of `Transactions` with your implementation. `JPA` does this for you. `JPA` is not a third party framework.

Comment: You question is a good fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @adrianp Thanks, I didn't know that that site existed until pretty much now.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the use of reflection in your `getData` method you should accept a factory that given a `ResultSet` creates instances of the specific type.  Your `selectAll` method would then be something like:

```
public static Map<String, Account> selectAll() 
{
  return getData(
    new EntityFactory<Account>()
    {
      public Account newInstance(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException
      {
        return new Account(resultSet.getString(0), resultSet.getString(1));
      }
    },
    SELECT_ALL_QUERY
  );
}
```

The `getData` method then ends up something like:

```
protected static <K, T extends Entity<K>> Map<K, T> getData(EntityFactory<T> entityFactory, String query) 
{
  Connection connection = null;
  PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;      
  ResultSet resultSet = null;

  try 
  {
    connection = dataSource.getConnection();

    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    Map<K, T> entities = new HashMap<>();

    while (resultSet.next()) 
    {
      Entity<K> entity = entityFactory.newInstance(resultSet);
      entities.put(entity.getKey(), entity);
    }

    return entities;
  }
  finally 
  {
    closeQuietly(resultSet);
    closeQuietly(prepareStatement);
    closeQuietly(connection);
  }
}
```

And assumes the `Entity` looks like:

```
public interface Entity<K>
{
  public K getKey();
}
```

This allows you to remove the reflection and keeps the code that understands the database structure in one place.  You should also use a similar template pattern to map from the domain object to the prepared statement when doing inserts and updates.

Now you've asked for comments on the code in general.

First off, code like this violates the [Single Responsibility Principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and [Seperation Of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).  A domain class should be a domain class and not contain persistance logic.  Look at patterns like the [Data Access Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) for how this should be done.

Second, while I'm all for keeping it simple, [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org) solved this problem a long time ago and [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html) standardized it - you need a very good reason not to use one or both of these APIs.

Finally, your use of database resources - if you are going to use JDBC directly you have to clean up properly.  Database connections are expensive resources and should be handled as such, the basic template for any JDBC call should be:

```
Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;

try 
{
  connection = //get connection from pool or single instance.

  preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = ?");
  preparedStatement.setString(1, "some string");

  resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

  while (resultSet.next())
  {
    //logic goes here.
  }
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
  //Handle exceptions.
}
finally 
{
  closeQuietly(resultSet);
  closeQuietly(prepareStatement);
  closeQuietly(connection);
}
```

The `closeQuietly` method has to be *overloaded* but should take the general form:

```
try 
{
  if (resultSet != null)
  {
    resultSet.close();
  }
}
catch (SQLException e)
{  
  //Log exceptions but don't re-throw.
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you can just pass around the ResultSet's like this, I would rather be thinking about passing one row around, but will look into that. For the rest seems nice, apart from one thing: Is there a general hate towards Generic Type Names that have more than one letter?

Comment: @swiki Generic type names have one letter by convention. It makes the code clearer because you direcly notice it is a Generic by its name and more important, it prevents from using the same name than an existing class.

Comment: Of course you can pass the result set like this, why do you think you can't?  The important bit is that the result set is controlled generically (created, iterated over and closed) in the base class, while the data is consumed in a class specialized to the particular case.  If you are still in doubt, you can see this pattern used repeatedly in Spring's JdbcTemplate (http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well, as Darwind and Nick Holt told you, in a normal situation, you should use [JPA](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/persistence-jsp-140049.html), which is the Java standard specification for object-relational mapping. You can use [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/), [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) or any other framework behind. Their design is  can manage connections, transactions. In addition, using standards rather than exotic frameworks means that you can get help more easily for the community.
 Another option is using Spring JDBC, which is quite light and facilitates many things.

Anyway, I suppose you did this for learning purpose so let's try to go further.

First, I think you should separate the classes in charge or retrieving the data (call it manager or Data Access Object -*DAO*-) and the entites representing the data themselves.

For me, using the class to get all the data as you did isn't a problem in itself. The problem is the position of the key is hardcoded. This should not be determined directly a generic (I mean the same for all the Entity implementation). This makes queries subjects to bugs when the first field is not the key (are you sure a `select * from...` will ALWAYS return the key in the first position? ) or with a composite key.
I think a better solution is to crate a `Mapper` interface and to implement it for each entity.

```
public interface RecordMapper<KeyType, DataType extends Entity> {
    public void appendToMap(ResultSet resultSet, Map<KeyType, DataType>) throws SQLException;
}
```

The implementation of the mapper should be in charge of instanciating your entity, retrieving the key from the resultset, populating your entity and putting it in the map you expect.

```
public class AccountMapper implement RecordMapper<String, Account>{
    public void appendToMap(ResultSet resultSet, Map<String, Account> accounts) throws SQLException {
        String user= resultSet.getString("userName");
        String pwd= resultSet.getString("passWord");
        Account account = new Account(user, pwd);
        accounts.put(user, account);
    }
}
```

As I told you should move your data access methods in a DAO:
    public class DAO{

```
    public <KeyType, DataType> Map<KeyType, DataType> getData(final RecordMapper<KeyType, DataType> mapper, final String query) {
        Map<KeyType, DataType> map = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = DatabaseConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                mapper.appendToMap(resultSet, map);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Entity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if(resultSet != null){
                try{resultSet.close();} catch (Exception e){}
            }
            if(preparedStatement!= null){
                try{preparedStatement.close();} catch (Exception e){}
            }
        }
        return map;
    }


    public void executeQuery(final String query, final List<Object> data) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = DatabaseConnection.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
            int dataIndex = 0;
            for (Object dataObject : data) {
                preparedStatement.setObject(dataIndex, dataObject);
                dataIndex++;
            }
            preparedStatement.execute();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Entity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if(resultSet != null){
                try{resultSet.close();} catch (Exception e){}
            }
            if(preparedStatement!= null){
                try{preparedStatement.close();} catch (Exception e){}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To answer your second quenstion, I think that putting your request string in the abstract parent instead of is certainly not a good idea. Each time you create new entity, you have to create a new query in the parent. Weird...unless I haven't understood properly your question.

Personnaly I think that the queries should be build dynamically and you should use [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) and [annotations](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAnnotations/article.html) but the answer should be a bit long. Once again, you can get a look at JPA to see how creating an entity should look like. By the way, it should be even better if the entities didn't have to extend a parent Entity class.